# Criação de um program em Python

Tags: python

Olá, não sou muito boa em programação, e estou com dificuldades nesse exercicio, esta dando erro já procurei e nao consigo solucionar... Gostaria que alguem me ajudasse a refazer esse codigo. Desde ja agradeço quem puder me ajudar

Crie um programa que leia um valor em reais e converta para dolar e euro. Necessario definir o valor de cada moeda

```
valor = float(input('Digite um valor em reais: '))
while opção != 2:
print('''[1] Dolar[2] Euro''')
opção = float(input('Digite sua opção: '))
if opção == 1:
calcular = valor * (3.70)
print('R$ {} é {} em dolares'.format(valor, calcular))
elif opção == 2:
calcular = valor * 4.24print('R$ {} é {} em euros'.format(valor, calcular))
else:
print('Opção invalida')
```

Comment: Considerando que seu código esteja propriamente indentado, o problema é que você está declarado uma variável com caracteres especiais, como ç e ã. Sempre declare variáveis sem acentos e sem cedilhas, isso vale para quase todas as linguagens de programação.

Comment: Juu, a indentação do seu código está toda errada na pergunta. Poderia nos dizer se seu código está **exatamente** assim ou se a indentação ficou errada só ao postar aqui?

Comment: @user129140 Não para Python, ele aceita acentuação sem problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente vamos analisar os problemas. Você precisa identar o seu código corretamente, é a base para desenvolver em python!

```
valor = float(input('Digite um valor em reais: '))

while opção != 2:
    print('''[1] Dolar[2] Euro''')
    opção = float(input('Digite sua opção: '))

    if opção == 1:
        calcular = valor * (3.70)
        print('R$ {} é {} em dolares'.format(valor, calcular))
    elif opção == 2:
        calcular = valor * 4.24
        print('R$ {} é {} em euros'.format(valor, calcular))
    else:
        print('Opção invalida')
```

Agora podemos ver o seguinte:

```
# Você está verificando o valor de opcao, antes mesmo de iniciá-la! 
while opção != 2:
    print('''[1] Dolar[2] Euro''')
    opção = float(input('Digite sua opção: '))
```

Quando você executar esse código, você vai cair nesse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 3, in <module>
    while opção != 2:
NameError: name 'opção' is not defined
```

Pra resolver isso, você precisa inicializar essa variável com um valor!

Fazendo isso, seu programa executará corretamente ;) 
Note que eu troquei o nome da variável opção por opcao, já que não é uma boa pratica em nenhuma linguagem de programação utilizar variáveis com Ç, acentos, etc.

```
valor = float(input('Digite um valor em reais: '))
opcao = 0

while opcao != 2:
    print('''[1] Dolar[2] Euro''')
    opcao = float(input('Digite sua opção: '))

    if opcao == 1:
        calcular = valor * (3.70)
        print('R$ {} é {} em dolares'.format(valor, calcular))
    elif opcao == 2:
        calcular = valor * 4.24
        print('R$ {} é {} em euros'.format(valor, calcular))
    else:
        print('Opção invalida')
```

Eu tomei a liberdade, e adicionei uma pequena validação para a opção selecionada, e adicionei uma terceira opção, que é para sair do programa

```
valor = float(input('Digite um valor em reais: '))
opcao = 0

while opcao != 3:
    print('''
          1 - Dolar
          2 - Euro
          3 - Sair
          ''')

    entrada = input('Digite sua opção: ')

    if entrada:
        try:
            opcao = int(entrada)
        except:
            print('Insira uma das opções informadas')
            continue

    if opcao == 1:
        calcular = valor * (3.70)
        print('R$ {} é {} em dolares'.format(valor, calcular))

    elif opcao == 2:
        calcular = valor * 4.24
        print('R$ {} é {} em euros'.format(valor, calcular))

    elif opcao == 3:
        print('Até mais ;)')

    else:
        print('Opção invalida')
```

Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar.

Grande abraço ;)

Comment: Poderia explicar o porquê de "não é uma boa pratica em nenhuma linguagem de programação utilizar variáveis com Ç, acentos"?

Comment: Pq as linguagens normalmente utilizam apenas caracteres contidos na tabela ascii, assim como o alfabeto em inglês. Se vc testar o seu codigo em python 2, vc verá q ele fará erro, simplesmente por uma string não reconhecer unicode

Answer (score -1):

Você está utilizando acentos em variáveis.
Não comece variáveis com Letras Maiúsculas e nem com caracteres especiais, caso tenha que utilizar 2 palavras em uma variável use `nome_grande` ou `nomeGrande` e nunca utilize acentos.

**Utilize** *\n* **para pular linha:**

```
print('--------\n[1] Dolar\n[2] Euro\n[0] Sair\n--------')
```

Seu `while` está: enquanto for diferente de 2 continue.
Criei uma variável chamada pergunta e atribui a ela o valor `True` do tipo *boolean*, enquanto o valor for True seu While vai ficar rodando.

**Adicionei:**

```
elif opcao == 0:
    # opcap for 0(ZERO) pergunta = False, While vai parar
    pergunta = False
```

Quando *opcao* for igual a zero:

A variável `pergunta` vai receber o valor de *False* e assim vai parar seu While.

```
# inicie o While como True
pergunta = True
valor = float(input('Digite um valor em reais: '))
#  Enquanto pergunta for True(Verdadeira) o While vai funcionar
while pergunta:
    print('--------\n[1] Dolar\n[2] Euro\n[0] Sair\n--------')
    opcao = float(input('Digite sua opção: '))
    if opcao == 1:
        calcular = valor * (3.70)
        print('R$ {} é {} em dolares'.format(valor, calcular))
    elif opcao == 2:
        calcular = valor * 4.24
        print('R$ {} é {} em euros'.format(valor, calcular))
    elif opcao == 0:
        # Opção for 0(ZERO) opcao = False, While vai parar
        pergunta = False
    else:
        print('Opção invalida')
```

Comment: O primeiro parágrafo da sua resposta não faz o mínimo de sentido. Python aceita sem problemas acentuação nos nomes de objetos, tanto com quanto funções.